# Replacing native search with WooCommerce Product search

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce

I'm running a theme name melokids, for a baby clothing store.

I'm struggling with trying to replace the theme's native search function with Woo Commerce, makes sense right?

Would appreciate if anybody would have any idea on this, Here's the current search function I believe:

```php
<?php
if(!function_exists('melokids_header_search')){
  function melokids_header_search($args=[]){
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, ['icon' => 'fa fa-search']);
    $header_search = melokids_get_opts('header_search','0');
    if('0' === $header_search) return;
    wp_enqueue_script('magnific-popup');
    wp_enqueue_style('magnific-popup');
    $unique_id = esc_attr( uniqid( 'search-form-' ) );
?>

<a href="#zk-header-search" class="mfp-search">
  <span class="<?php echo esc_attr($args['icon']);?>"></span>
</a>
<div id="zk-header-search" class="mfp-hide">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="search" id="<?php echo esc_attr($unique_id); ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Type something to search ...', 'placeholder', 'melokids' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'melokids' ); ?></span></button>
  </form>
</div>

<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search form-inline" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-0" class="search-field form-control" placeholder="Search…" value="" name="s">
    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn">Search</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    </form>
```

try this